# Android Wear App Layouts & Notifcations

Tags: android, android-layout, android-intent, android-notifications, wear-os

I only started coding with Android Wear recently so bear with me. I want to develop a project but I'm stuck on the best way to go about it. I have been looking at the Wear documentation but I'm still confused.

For my app, I created 10 notifications on the mobile, this was fine. But what I want to happen is, when I click a button on my handheld, it sends these 10 notifications to wear. Once wear device receives them, it first displays a start page with an action to start. When I click the start action on the wear interface...I want to display the stream of 10 notifications.  I want each notification on a different page or card. Each notification staying until I swipe it away. Also each notification having a different background.

Is this possible? If so, what is the best approach to use?

Any help would be much appreciated.

Cheers.